# Rails 4 Import unknown fields to serialized hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, import

I have a model that consists of several fields ie (Name, Description) and a properties column which is a serialized hash of custom attributes.

I am trying to write an import script to handle importing a CSV/XLS file into the database for this model and am struggling with capturing all of the unknown database fields and serializing them with their header into the properties column as a hash.

ie with the following table.

### Name | Description | Field1 | Field2

Row1 | This is     | Row1F1 | Row1F2

Row2 | This is     | Row2F1 | Row2F2

I would like it to import into the database as

Testmodel.create(:name => Row1, :description => "This is", :properties => { :field1 => "Row1F1", :field2 => "Row1F2" })

My current SIMPLE import that I use for my other simple tables is the following. I am using [Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)

```
 def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    chemuse = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    chemuse.attributes = row.to_hash
    chemuse.save!
  end
end
```

My goal is for the import to catch unknown column names and then I will put them into a hash and add them to the :properties column.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the following code that works but it doesn't seem very efficient but wanted to post it as an answer.

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  cn = column_names
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    rawrow = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    cleansedrow = {:properties => {}}
    rawrow.each do |key, value|
      if cn.include?(key)
        cleansedrow[key] = value
      else
        cleansedrow[:properties][key] = value
      end
    end
    record = find_by_id(cleansedrow["id"]) || new
    record.attributes = cleansedrow.to_hash
    record.save!
  end
end
```